# Catalan Number Proof

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

We know for Catalan Numbers,there are:
$$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$and $$C_0 = 1,\qquad C_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n} C_i\, C_{n-i}\,.$$But how can I plug the upper one into the lower one and check if it really works or not through algebraic manipulation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Fifth_proof

Comment: thanks, but they invited Dyck Words to prove it and that one is a inverse proof to my question. Can you come up with a pure algebraic manipulation solution? That would be what I (the professor) am seeking.Thank you in advance.